# TCP/IP client reconnect after server shutdown

Tags: c++, tcp

I have a situation where the server that the client connects to may get repeatly shutdown with the client still operational.

In the current implementation, when the client fails a read it will call `close(sockFd)` to close the socket. Then it will it loop to try to recreate that socket.

Is that best practice? Or is it possible to leave the socket and attempt to connect to it?

Edit: Platform is Linux

Comment: This is a platform-specific question. There is no universal C++ API for TCP.

Comment: According to the BSD sockets quasi-standard, trying to call `connect` again on a socket that's closed or errored should raise EINVAL (22). On some platforms, it actually works anyway, but that certainly isn't safe portably, and it's not even documentated on the platforms where it works. More importantly, there's really no advantage to it; the time it takes to create a new socket object with `socket` is minuscule compared to the time it takes to set up the TCP connection with `connect`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The fact that he talks about sockets and socket APIs implies that he's talking about BSD/POSIX/WinSock2/etc. sockets, which is pretty close to universal (as long as you ignore the minor differences); there aren't too many platforms that have TCP support but don't have sockets.

Comment: The code is operating Linux environment, will edit the OP. The intent of the question was more about the way the client should reconnection plus cleanup if neccessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get any error other than `EINTR` or `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` on a socket it is almost certainly dead and must be closed. @abarnert gives some others in the useful comment below.

Comment: Of course `EINTR` doesn't kill the socket. And there are some errors that are defined specifically as leaving the socket alive, most obviously `EINPROGRESS` (it wouldn't be very useful otherwise), although the exact list is platform-specific. Finally, some errors (e.g., an `EFAULT` from passing a NULL pointer) usually won't kill the socket, but are hard to recover from for other reasons. Anyway, generally this is the right idea.